# How to Import CSV and Excel Data and saving it in SQLite database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

i want to import CSV and Excel  Data to SQLite database. there is tool available sqlBulkCopy but its only for SQL Server

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the real problem? Transfer file to server, reading data from CSV/Excel, writing data to SQLite? At now you are asking for all of them and that is **too broad** for a question on SO

Comment: CSVDataAdapter CSVda = new CSVDataAdapter(@"c:\FileName.csv");

Comment: I am using CSVDataAdapter  but its not working ..

Comment: Put that details into the question not in the comments. "not working" can be anything from no reaction to exploding computer, so please specify this "not working" because we cannot see on your computer or into your brain

Answer (score 0):

If this is one-time import you can use [sqlite3.exe command line](https://sqlite.org/cli.html) utility that can load CSV data into SQLite database (for Excel file it should be saved as CSV before import):

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import C:/work/somedata.csv tab1
```

In case if import should be automated with C# use the following packages:

- Read CSV files of any size: [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)
- Read Excel files (open-XML only): [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)
- Connect to SQLite database: [System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.Core/) (.NET Framework only) or [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SQLite/) (supports both net451 and .NET Core)

Note that you don't need to use some kind of SqlBulkCopy: SQLite is embedded database engine and usual inserts provide fast enough way of importing large datasets (40k-80k inserts per second). Don't forget to execute inserts batch in transaction (say, for every 100k rows).

You may use SQLite ADO.NET connector directly or use libraries like [NReco.Data](https://github.com/nreco/data) to simplify SQL command preparation (in offers lightweight `RecordSet` structure that can be used for inserting many records in effective way).

Comment: Dear Sir what about "," i don't want add "," for column splits because my data contains lat lang  so it makes it different column.

Comment: i want column split by cell

Comment: @Mrittunjaysharma correct CSV file can be parsed with CSVHelper library; as provides you each CSV row as array of strings.